# Compute test error and std of a model

Tags: confidence-interval, python, standard-error

I would like to do the following:

- Train a classifier on a certain dataset
- Test the classifier on a certain test set
- Compute the test error and standard deviation
- Compute a 95% confidence interval for the true error

I have a training set `X_train` with 1000 training examples, each having 15 features. The true labels are in `Y_train`. I also have a test set of `X_test`, with the true labels in `Y_test`.

So far, I have come up with the following code:

```
scores = np.zeros(1000)

clf = RandomForestClassifier(criterion='entropy')
clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
for i in range(1000):
    score = clf.score(X_test[i], [Y_test[i]])
    scores[i] = score
```

The above code fits the model with the training set and then uses the `clf.score` method on every test example separately. Consequently, the `scores` array is a binary array, because each time a singleton is tested and this is either correctly or incorrectly classified. Next, I compute the test error and standard deviation like this:

```
ctr = 0
for i in scores:
    if i == 0:
        ctr += 1

test_error = ctr/1000.0
std = scores.std()
```

I assume the data is approximated by a Normal Distribution since I have 1000 training examples. Then, I compute the 95% confidence interval for the true error like this:

```
med = test_error
low = test_error - 1.645 * math.sqrt(std)
high = test_error + 1.645 * math.sqrt(std)
```

My question is: is this a correct way of computing the test error and the 95% confidence interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 95% confidence interval is incorrect. I think the formula you are looking for is $testError \pm t_{d.f.,\frac{\alpha}{2}} * StdErr$

The first term, $t_{d.f.,\frac{\alpha}{2}}$, is the t-value for a specific $d.f. = degreesOfFreedom$ and $\alpha$. The degrees of freedom follows the size of the test set and is simply $n-1=999$. And $\alpha$ is the significance level you are looking for, in this case $\alpha=0.05$. However, since you are computing a two-sided 95% confidence interval, then the t-value is 1.96 since there will be 2.5% on each side. 1.645 is the one-sided t-value. When you are looking up the t-value make sure to check if the table is reporting one-sided or two-sided values .

Also, we use the [t-table instead of a z-table](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31455/confusing-regarding-when-to-use-z-statistics-vs-t-statistics) because we are estimating our variance from our data instead of using a known variance. For small data sizes (and small d.f.), notice how the t-value is larger than the corresponding z-value. And as the data size increases (and d.f. increases), we gain more confidence in our variance estimate and the t-value approaches the z-value. Since this test set is so large, the t-value can simply be replaced by the z-value.

Finally, the standard error is incorrect. Square root is taken of the variance: $std=\sqrt{var}$. But most importantly, the confidence interval of mean error uses the [Central Limit Theorem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3734/what-intuitive-explanation-is-there-for-the-central-limit-theorem). As the test set gets larger, you should be more confident that the mean error is correct and the interval will get smaller. $StdErr=\frac{std}{\sqrt{n}}$

In this case, the specific equation is

$testError \pm 1.96 * \frac{std}{\sqrt{1000}}$

Comment: What is the definition of $t_{999,\alpha/2}$? What is $\alpha$?

Comment: Thank you @mpiktas for the suggestion. I've updated the post.