# Learning ML/NLP from electronics & communication engineering background

Tags: machine-learning

I study Electronics & Communication Engineering. I like Computer Sciences. Out of pure passion, I even studied few programming languages like Java, Python etc

I studied probability, math, computer architecture, Java, C at college.

I think Machine Learning, NLP etc stuff are fun for me. I never studied these subjects but I can say with the idea I have on them. So, can you please answer the below questions

1. I am even thinking to apply internships, can I apply in ML/NLP areas? What are the chances that I will get accepted?
2. Is a strong knowledge in ML/NLP is required to pursue UG internship in those areas? Is a strong desire to learn not enough?

Comment: Have you searched the site? There are a number of questions that cover this information, such as: [machine-learning-cookbook-reference-card-cheatsheet](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12386/); [programmer-looking-to-break-into-machine-learning-field](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26044/); [is-a-strong-background-in-maths-a-total-requisite-for-ml](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40808/); [how-to-get-started-with-neural-networks](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36247/), etc. If you can refine your Q it may be answerable, otherwise it may need to be closed.

Answer (score 3):

You should take advantage of free, high quality material which is available to everyone. There are extremely popular online courses such as Andrew Ng's Coursera course or his related Stanford class with lectures on Youtube. If you haven't gone through one of these, or analogous material elsewhere, you should do so. If you haven't at least done this much, while tens or hundreds of thousands of others have, your application probably won't look so great in comparison, and your professions of passion will sound hollow and superficial.